# Postman PUT request doesn't update content but no error

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, put

I'm using postman with springboot i have already used the GET/POST/DELETE requests and they all work fine but PUT request doesn't update content .

In intellij i'm using these files :

Student.java(with it's setters and getters) :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name="student_sequence",
        sequenceName="student_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "student_sequence"
)
private Long id;
private String name;

private LocalDate dob;
private  String email;
@Transient
private Integer age;
```

StudentController.java :

```
@PutMapping(path ="{studentId}")
public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String email)
{
    studentService.updateStudent(studentId,name,email);
}
```

StudentService.java :

```
@Transactional
public void updateStudent(Long studentId,String name, String email)
{
   Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                   "student with id="+studentId+"does not exist"));
   if (name !=null && name.length()>0  && !Objects.equals(student.getName(),name))
   {
       student.setName(name);
   }
   if (email !=null && email.length()>0 && !Objects.equals(student.getEmail(),email))
   {
       Optional<Student> studentOptional= studentRepository.findStudentByEmail(email);
       if (studentOptional.isPresent())
       {
           throw new IllegalStateException("email taken");
       }
       student.setEmail(email);
   }
 }
```

[These are the students that i have in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvdvQ.jpg)
And basically i want to update the name and email of the student with id=1.

[That is postman header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwBmQ.jpg)

[And that is postman not showing any error after sending request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6DGY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

using `@RequestParam(required = false) String name` the params are expected as header or query param. You're sending a request body, so use a pojo instead...

```
class StudentDto {

  public String name;
  //...

}
```

and the controller ...

```
@PutMapping(path ="{studentId}")
public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
        @RequestBody StudentDto) {
  //...

}
```

Comment: What if i just remove the @RequestParam(required = false) and let the rest as it is ?

Comment: no idea what the spring default is like... try it...

Answer (score 0):

To leave it be and make it work, you have to put your data as query params, lik ethis

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/student/1?name=newName&email=newEmailToSet
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but i have already tried doing this and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So after this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72698172/19354780
i have tried changing StudentController to :

```
@PutMapping(path = "{studentId}")
public void updateStudent(
        @PathVariable("studentId") Long studentId,
        @RequestBody Student new_student) {
    studentService.updateStudent(studentId, new_student);

}
```

and StudentService to :

```
 @Transactional
 public void updateStudent(Long studentId,Student new_student)
 {
   Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                   "student with id="+studentId+"does not exist"));
   if (new_student.getName() !=null && new_student.getName().length()>0  && !Objects.equals(student.getName(),new_student.getName()))
   {
       student.setName(new_student.getName());
   }
   if (new_student.getEmail() !=null && new_student.getEmail().length()>0 && !Objects.equals(student.getEmail(),new_student.getEmail()))
   {
       Optional<Student> studentOptional= studentRepository.findStudentByEmail(new_student.getEmail());
       if (studentOptional.isPresent())
       {
           throw new IllegalStateException("email taken");
       }
       student.setEmail(new_student.getEmail());
   }
   }
```

and it worked but without the exceptions .